# C# app create objects from Java classes?

Tags: c#, java, interop

Can a C# app create objects defined in Java `.class` files?

Is any interop between C# and Java possible, with C# as the host language?

Comment: @JeffN825: will that allow me in C# to create objects from `.class` files and call their methods?

Comment: I do not think so. Run time for both the languages are different. How do you suppose you would load .class file in .Net Runtime until there is some interop available

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a combination of PInvoke and JNI.

You will have to create classes in Java. Expose them via JNI. Access these through PInvoke in C#. You have a to and fro communication between C# to Java.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PInvoke

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Answer (score 0):

If you need direct instantiation you need [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/) otherwise you can expose the Java program as a server and communicate with any RPC technology (TCP, http etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) in the past.  It works well for large projects, but might be too much for you.  It all depends on where you're going with this.  But if you want complete interop it's worth looking into.

Otherwise, if you an expain your intentions better someone might have a better idea.